# auth0lock : Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined

Tags: auth0-lock

I have a simple NodeJS file named index.js includes the following lines:

```
const {Auth0Lock} = require('auth0-lock');
var lock = new Auth0Lock( MyClientId,  MyDomain);    
lock.show();
```

I used `npm install auth0-lock` to install auth0lock and have the proper `package.json` file. When I run this piece of code by `node index.js`, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\....\node_modules\auth0-lock\lib\utils\url_utils.js:6
var parser = global.document.createElement('a');
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
```

Also, when I change `const {Auth0Lock} = require('auth0-lock')` to `const Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock')`, I get the following error:

```
    var lock = new Auth0Lock(
           ^
    TypeError: Auth0Lock is not a constructor
```

Would you please help me to fix this error and have an auth0lock authentication dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auth0-lock with NodeJS you need to use a bundler like webpack or browserify.

Please refer to this [repo](https://github.com/auth0/lock/tree/b66b79917d66b76184e835fa760c80f40ee4aebb/examples/bundling/webpack): for setup configuration with webpack.
Alternativel